# Compile and build the cobbler source code rpm for fedora

Tags: linux, build, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

Recently I read this post http://howto.basjes.nl/linux/doing-pxe-without-dhcp-control and want to try using cobbler.

Because I need the latest cobbler to run on my Fedora and I need to compile and install from the source code instead of using `yum install`. I am a beginner of linux programming and want to know more.

I did my research on the cobbler [documentation wiki on Github](https://github.com/cobbler/cobbler/wiki/Download%20Instructions) and it shows a very simple guide on "**Source RPM Build Instructions for Fedora**"

```
Install python-setuptools and python-devel from yum
rpmbuild --rebuild cobbler*.src.rpm
install the RPM, which is now built in /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/noarch
satisfy any dependencies you have by using yum and the stock Fedora repos
```

I downloaded the source code from Github and got the error message when execute `rpmbuild --rebuild cobbler*.src.rpm` under the "cobbler" folder. Saying `"there is no such cobbler*.src.rpm"` exist.

I gave it another shot by running "make install" and it seems working as i see there are outputs but I cannot find the output file?

Could anyone show me how to compile and install the cobbler source code on Fedora 16 please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a target built into the Makefile to build the rpms. So assuming you have all the required tools installed simply issuing this command in the root of the source tree

```
make rpms
```

should build a set of rpms into the rpm-build subdirectory within the source root.

P.S. I usually use CentOS and I needed to add the EPEL repository to get the PyYAML rpm (needed to built the cobbler rpms)

Comment: I installed relevant packages for Fedora (PyYAML rpm etc.) and ran "make rpms". It seems fine but at the end shows error: 'Installed (but  unpackeged) files found: /usr/share/augeas/lenses/cobblersettings.aug' When I check the /usr/share/augeas/lenses directory using 'ls' command I couldn't find any files in there.